# Image not shown properly in firefox

Tags: html, css, image, google-chrome, firefox

If the image is not available in the folder then browser only show img tag with its given height and width but firefox creates problem in this case..

**Problem** : I am using img attribute to show an image. In firefox it looks like 
i am using style="width: 180px; height: 185px;"

[image]

but in chrome it looks like

[image]

Comment: Can you add you code here or fiddle it?

Comment: post your code here or share the link with us....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
@-moz-document url-prefix(http), url-prefix(file) {
    img:-moz-broken{
    -moz-force-broken-image-icon:1;
    width:180px;
    height:185px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    }
}
```

[Example jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9bKW2/).

**EDIT: The solution posted by Gaurav is better, use it instead.**

> -moz-force-broken-image-icon
>
> The use of this property is not recommended. A proper alt attribute should be used instead.

Comment: it works fine in mozilla but not in chrome. can you please provide code for both

Comment: You want to remove the image placeholder in Chrome?

Answer (score 1):

Remove attribute `alt=""` it will work in Mozilla as well.

<kbd>**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/KsU3p/3/)**</kbd>

HTML

```
<img src="youImage.jpg" style="width: 180px; height: 185px;"/>
```

Mozilla

[image]

Chrome

[image]

---

**If you wish to have alt as well  <kbd>**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/KsU3p/4/)</kbd>** **

Comment: thanks for the answer but i am already not using alt in the img